# Unzip a file in S3 using EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have uploaded a really large file in S3. I need to unzip it but I don't know how to deal with it. It seems that it is necessary to use a EC2. Please, can anybody tell me how must I proceed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to download a copy of the file to somewhere other than S3, because you can't unzip files directly on S3. You will have to download it, unzip it, and then upload the unzipped version to S3.

An EC2 server would be a good way to do this because it will have very fast access to S3.

Beyond that, your question is too broad for this site. Come back and ask specific questions if you run into specific issues.

Comment: Thanks Mark, my apologies but in my opinion my question is a specific one, just need to know how to unzip zip file in s3

Comment: You can't "unzip file in s3". That isn't something S3 supports. So the answer to that is "you can't". Given that, your question sounds more like a question about how to create and use an EC2 server, and that is a very broad question.

Answer (score -1):

Just to share how I got it:

**EC2**

- export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=your key
- export AWS_SECRET_KEY=your secret key
- source ~/.bashrc
- Upload your .zip file
- Unzip your file
- aws s3 cp file s3://yourBucket/folder/fileName

Hope it can be useful.
Thanks

Comment: If you'll add some code this answer can be excepted. Need more than just your method.

Comment: What do you mean by Unzip your file here? Because I am experiencing unzip command not found on an ec2 box.